# how to build log in api using php

Tags: php, android

I would like to build log in api using php 
to use it in my android project 
I have tried and I wrote this code ::

```
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
$db =getDB();
$json = $app->request->getBody();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
if (isset($data['Email']) && isset($data['Password'])) {
$email = $data['Email'];
$password = $data['Password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `Email` = '".$email."'";
$result = $db->query($sql);


if (mysql_num_rows($result)> 0 ) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


    if ($password == $row['Password']) {
        $post["message"] = "LogIn successfull";
    } else {
        $post["message"] = "Wrong Email or Password";
    }

} else {
    $post["message"] = "Try again";
}
} 
  else { $post["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing"; 
 } 
echo json_encode($post);

});
```

I think the problem here

```
$ Sql = "SELECT * FROM` User` WHERE `Email` = '". $ Email. "'";
$ Result = $ db-> query ($ sql);
```

I want after the query is executed, the value stored in the variable result
 Then extract all the columns of this variable to get the password

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting?

Comment: Also, it seems that you are storing passwords as plain text (not related the issue you are facing) which is a sin. Use, at least, md5 hash to store the passwords

Comment: there is no error , but when when i execute the sql query

Comment: the return value is true or false ,, i need the information about user

Comment: i know the pass should store at least md5 hash but now i am testing my api just